# Triggers VS Converters

Tags: c#, xaml

First of all, I know to use both triggers and converters, but I have some questions that I am still not sure about the answers.

1. When is it preferable to use triggers over converters?
2. What is better performance - triggers or converters?
3. Does everything that converter does is possible to do with triggers and the opposite?

One more thing, triggers are not that good because it is writing a logic in the XAML, which is wrong, and often not readable, especially if we write many triggers in one page, so most time I prefer to use converters.  Does my opinion sound correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converters are used to change data from your internal format to one that can be displayed on the UI and interacted with by the user. So for example, you would have a converter to change an enumeration type to the selected value of a combo box, or change a boolean to "visible"/"invisible",  or use a converter to show and hide or enable and disable different parts of the UI when a property has a certain value.

Triggers allow you change other parts of the UI based on the change in value of a property. This would include things like:

- highlighting other parts of the UI (changing colour for example)
- initiating animations

There is some overlap, but I would use converters when the change to the UI is static - e.g. a tab is *always* disabled when the mode is set to certain value, while triggers are for more dynamic changes - highlighting, animations etc, that are triggered by user actions.

As you say triggers are putting logic in the UI, but I would use them for logic that is just changing the UI in some way, not triggering changes in the model itself.